# getElementsByTagName inside GetElementById (object xraywrapper)?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a `div` that is inside another `div`, since the id of the second `div` is variable, i use

```
var wrappingdiv = document.getElementById('divId')
```

to get the wrapping div then

```
var insidediv = wrappingdiv.getElementsByTagName('div')
```

but i get the `getElementsByTagName` is not a function error, i guess the syntax is wrong, could you guys put me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Edit :  I will correct myself, I am trying to get the body of a gmail email, so :

```
var element = content.document.getElementsByClassName("ii gt m13fbe3a51e95e196 adP adO");
```

it returns an `object xraywrapper[object htmlcollection]`

Edit 2 :

I am using mozilla firefox, and i am developing my own extension, to access source code of Google mail i use simple javascript (content.document...)

Comment: A jsfiddle would be nice.

Comment: seems fine at http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/snkV4/1/ also which is the browser used

Comment: Include the HTML you're working with. Your code should be all-right, unless there is no element with ID `'divId'` (note that IDs are case-sensitive!).

Comment: Thanks a lot, i am using mozilla firefox

Comment: Perhaps your code is running before the DOM has completed loading? You really need to give some more information, otherwise it is all just guessing.

Comment: The `object xraywrapper[object htmlcollection]` perhaps doesn't know getElementById method

Comment: What browser are you using? What extensions are you using for this, FireBug? How are you injecting your code into Google Mail page or perhaps you are ajaxing the document? Too many unknowns.

Comment: I am using mozilla firefox, and i am developing my own extension, to access source code of Google mail i use simple javascript (content.document...)

Comment: What is an `xraywrapper` and where can I get one?!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XPConnect_wrappers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
var element = content.document.getElementsByClassName(
    "ii gt m13fbe3a51e95e196 adP adO");
```

`getElements` <- the `s` means this returns ***multiple elements*** (in a list-like collection), not just one element.

You might just want to pick out the first one it found.

```
var element = content.document.getElementsByClassName(
    "ii gt m13fbe3a51e95e196 adP adO")[0];
```

There is also a small risk that it might not be `m13fbe3a51e95e196` on every page, or forever.  So perhaps you should generalise your search a bit.  How about just searching for class `"adP"`?

Comment: You are a life saver thanks a lot, i apologies for the confusion in the beginning

Answer (score 3):

If you doesn't have any element with the id `divId` then `wrappingdiv` will be equal null:

And when trying to get `null.getElementsByTagName` you will get a type error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null

Answer (score 1):

The syntax isn't wrong. `document.getElementById('divId')` probably just fails to match the id of any existing element, so it returns `null` (which doesn't have a `getElementsByTagName` method).

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XDFxC/)

```
  var wrappingdiv = document.getElementById("divId");
  var insidediv = wrappingdiv.getElementsByTagName('div');
  var i = 0;
    for(i=0;i<insidediv.length;i++)
    alert(insidediv[i].innerHTML);
```

Comment: I get the is not a function error error here : `wrappingdiv.getElementsByTagName('div');`